# Why does the javascript part of my html file doesn't seem to work as it is supposed?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Why doesn't this programme work? It is an error in the javascript part of the html file. It is supposed to send a certain text into my firebase database.

```html
<html>
<style>
  h1{
    text-align:center;
  }
  #div1{
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <h1>SEND A MESSAGE</h1>
  <div id="div1">
    <input id="textbox1">
    <button id="btn1">Send</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script id="MainScript">
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function(){
    firebase.database().ref("Message/"+"name").set({
      message: "message",
      id: "hy"
    });
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it cannot resolve the reference for "firebase". Try changing your script source to point to the hosted libraries instead

```
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase- 
app.js"></script>

<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase- 
auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase- 
firestore.js"></script>
<script defer src="./init-firebase.js"></script>
```